# Inline list within text / header

Tags: html, css

I want to display a list within a header (which is animated). I want the list to sit with the rest of the text. I set the UL to display:inline-block expecting the li to sit on the baseline, but it does not:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}

.cycle {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
  
}

 li {
     animation: word-cycle 2.5s linear infinite 0s;
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   
.cycle li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes word-cycle {
  20%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>This is some text with a list:

  <ul class="cycle">
    <li>One</li>
     <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
       <li>four</li>
        <li>fice</li>
        
  </ul>

</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}

h1{ 
    display: inline;
    position: relative;

}
.cycle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
}

 li {
     animation: word-cycle 2.5s linear infinite 0s;
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     visibility: hidden;
   }
   
.cycle li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes word-cycle {
  20%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>This is some text with a list:

  <ul class="cycle">
    <li>One</li>
     <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
       <li>four</li>
        <li>fice</li>
        
  </ul>

</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `li` positioned `absolute` remove that and it will go inline.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
h1{
display: flex;
}

.cycle {
display:inline-block;
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
  
}

 li {
     animation: word-cycle 2.5s linear infinite 0s;
     position: absolute;
     top:0;
     visibility: hidden;
     margin-left: 10px;
   }
   
.cycle li:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.cycle li:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes word-cycle {
  20%,
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  0% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>This is some text with a list:

  <ul class="cycle">
    <li>One</li>
     <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
       <li>four</li>
        <li>fice</li>
        
  </ul>
</h1>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Removing this does put the text in the right place, but it has to be positioned absolute, because I want all LI on the same line.

Comment: What you want with all `li` on the same line. Can you edit your question to show another `li` and how you want to show them.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the animated list.

Comment: Alright, I got it. But, in the update you `li` is inline with your `h1`

Comment: I did not have my padding / margin reset. Have updated.